# Add one fore each identical index

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
l = ['a','b','c','a','a','c'] 
l1 = ['a1','b','c1','a2','a3','c2']
```

I've a list that looks like this, and if there is more then one index that are identical I want to add one so that the list looks like l1 but I can´t figure out how

Answer (score 0):

Using brute force

```
l = ['a','b','c','a','a','c'] 
b = set(l)
for elem in b:
    count = l.count(elem)
    if count > 1:
        dup = 1
        for i in range(len(l)):
            if l[i] == elem:
                l[i] = l[i] + str(dup)
                dup += 1
print('l: ', l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = ['a','b','c','a','a','c'] 
counts = {v:list(range(1, l.count(v)+1)) for v in l}
l1 = [x if counts[x] == [1] else '%s%s' % (x, counts[x].pop(0)) for x in l]
print(l1)
```

Output:

```
['a1', 'b', 'c1', 'a2', 'a3', 'c2']
```